# Could not set unknown property 'configFile' for object of type net.corda.plugins.Node

Tags: corda

Follow the sample build.gradle codes in [this documentation page](https://docs.corda.net/generating-a-node.html?highlight=configFile), I added one "configFile" into node's definition here, but after refreshed the gradle project, when build the app there is an error:

```
Could not set unknown property 'configFile' for object of type net.corda.plugins.Node.
```

Did I miss adding anything in the build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Set the configFile without '=' sign.
For Eg:
configFile  "/Users/mac_user/Documents/resources/nodea.conf" in node of the build.gradle file.